# pycocotools fails to install on python 3.7 0r 3.6

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, faster-rcnn, pycocotools

`I want to install pycocotools in python 3.7 version.(basically downgrade to 3.7)

!pip install -q pycocotools

I used this above command in google colab.

But i got some error. Please help me in this regard.

I am expecting to run the pycocotools in this notebook and help me to run the colab notebook.
[https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z_IIrTRSxZ7ATVbWSpaLd_a8yBT-d5d2?usp=sharing][1]

Output:

```
Collecting pycocotools
  Using cached pycocotools-2.0.6.tar.gz (24 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting matplotlib>=2.1.0 (from pycocotools)
  Using cached matplotlib-3.5.3-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (11.2 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from pycocotools) (1.19.5)
Collecting cycler>=0.10 (from matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools)
  Using cached cycler-0.11.0-py3-none-any.whl (6.4 kB)
Collecting fonttools>=4.22.0 (from matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools)
  Using cached fonttools-4.38.0-py3-none-any.whl (965 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1 (from matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools)
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.4.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting packaging>=20.0 (from matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools)
  Using cached packaging-23.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting pillow>=6.2.0 (from matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools)
  Using cached Pillow-9.5.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.4 MB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.2.1 (from matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools)
  Using cached pyparsing-3.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7 (from matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from kiwisolver>=1.0.1->matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools) (4.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7->matplotlib>=2.1.0->pycocotools) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycocotools
  **error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
Failed to build pycocotools
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-**`
`
``


  [1]: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z_IIrTRSxZ7ATVbWSpaLd_a8yBT-d5d2?authuser=2#scrollTo=Qjc1R2agAbTv
```

Comment: Hi @shahriar sajal, Google Colab is upgraded to python version 3.10 and there is no fallback runtime available currently to use previous python version.  `pycocotools` package is already installed in current Google Colab. Please check this Colab [gist](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/RenuPatelGoogle/c0ac277f1bdbf6aa77b2fbd903cdd28b/76211708.ipynb) for your reference